# How do I add a class to an a href after the page loads

Tags: jquery, drupal

So, I have 3 buttons that are links, and when one is clicked I want to add the '.active' class to it, and I thought this code would work

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.filterbuttons').click(function() {
        jQuery('.filterbuttons').removeClass("active");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

It adds the class, but then the page loads (becuase I clicked the link) and the .active class goes away. 
How do I have a .click function, which then adds the class after the page loads again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you click the link everything is reloaded according to the html of the linked page. The scripts are loaded in their original state.

you could get the url of the page and, according to the url, add the class to the appropriate button as follows

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.includes(partOfTheURLThatDistinguishesMyPage)) {
     $(appropriateButton).addClass("active"); 
}
```

hope that's useful. elaborates a bit on the previous answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with an on click event, once the page loads you'll lose the class. You could possibly add the class to the specific button based on some unique content of the new page that was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be setting a filter that you want to then take action on which gives you a couple choices that might provide the behavior you want with a slight changes in approach.

- Set a parameter in the URL that you can then read back in JS later (something similar to @EmOnTheWeb's response). Since this question includes the Drupal tag you are likely using a module like views with exposed filters enabled. If you have a custom module on the Drupal side you could also set an active class during the page reload (how exactly you'd do that depends on a lot of details you left out).
- Use [preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to make sure the page does not reload. Then in your click handler do whatever you need for filtering and display update.